# Filtering an array with multiple filter arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I'm trying to filter an array of items based on multiple filter arrays. Each of the items has a selection of filters, and I need to show only the ones that match all of the selected filters.

```
const selectedFilters = {
    color: ["Red", "Blue"],
    type: ["Shirt"],
    size: ["M"]
};

const items = [
    {
        name: "Item 1",
        filters: {
            color: ["Red", "Blue", "Black"],
            type: ["Shirt"],
            size: ["M"]
        }
    },
    {
        name: "Item 2",
        filters: {
            color: ["Red"],
            type: ["Pants"],
            size: ["M"]
        }
    }
];
```

This is how I've been trying to solve it. Filter through all of the items - for each filter category that is not empty, go through all the filter words and check that the item matches all of them.

```
const filterItems = (items, selectedFilters) => {
    const filterKeys = Object.keys(selectedFilters);

    return items.filter(item => {
        return filterKeys.every(key => {

            // Ignore empty filters
            if (!selectedFilters[key].length) {
                return true;
            }

            return selectedFilters[key].every(filterWord => {
                item.filters[key].includes(filterWord);
            });
        });
    });
};

filterItems(items, selectedFilters);
```

Returns an empty array, should return an array with the "Item 1" object.

Comment: I added an answer to your question.

Comment: Actually, your solution is totally correct, you're just missing `return` inside the `every` callback: `return item.filters[key].includes(filterWord)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the array of values of `selectedFilters` as well array of `filters` property values. Then use `every` on `selectedFilters` to check if all values in it are present within the `filters`.

```js
const selectedFilters = {
    color: ["Red", "Blue"],
    type: ["Shirt"],
    size: ["M"]
};

const items = [
    {
        name: "Item 1",
        filters: {
            color: ["Red", "Blue", "Black"],
            type: ["Shirt"],
            size: ["M"]
        }
    },
    {
        name: "Item 2",
        filters: {
            color: ["Red"],
            type: ["Pants"],
            size: ["M"]
        }
    }
];

const filterArr = Object.values(selectedFilters).flat();

const output = items.filter(({filters}) => {
    const objFilters = Object.values(filters).flat();
    return filterArr.every(val => objFilters.includes(val));
})
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some` to check at least one element is included in the array and the function expects a bool return value.

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array
>   passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a
>   Boolean value.

```js
const selectedFilters = {"color":["Red","Blue"],"type":["Shirt"],"size":["M"]}
const items = [{"name":"Item 1","filters":{"color":["Red","Blue","Black"],"type":["Shirt"],"size":["M"]}},{"name":"Item 2","filters":{"color":["Red"],"type":["Pants"],"size":["M"]}}]

const filterItems = (items, selectedFilters) => {
  const filterKeys = Object.keys(selectedFilters);
  return items.filter(item => {
    return filterKeys.every(key => {
      return selectedFilters[key].some(filterWord => {   //Use some
        return item.filters[key].includes(filterWord);   //Return the a bool
      });
    })
  });
};

var result = filterItems(items, selectedFilters);
console.log(result);
```

Shorter version:

```js
const selectedFilters = {"color":["Red","Blue"],"type":["Shirt"],"size":["M"]};

const items = [{"name":"Item 1","filters":{"color":["Red","Blue","Black"],"type":["Shirt"],"size":["M"]}},{"name":"Item 2","filters":{"color":["Red"],"type":["Pants"],"size":["M"]}}];

const filterItems = (items, selectedFilters) => {
  const fkeys = Object.keys(selectedFilters);
  return items.filter(i => fkeys.every(k => selectedFilters[k].some(o => i.filters[k].includes(o))));
};

const result = filterItems(items, selectedFilters);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array.filter() function for this. Here is the very simple and effective solution fo this.

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(arr2) {
    var ret = [];
    for(var i in this) {   
        if(arr2.indexOf(this[i]) > -1){
            ret.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
};

var filteredArr = items.filter(function (el) {
  return el.filters.color.diff(selectedFilters.color).length > 0 &&
         el.filters.type.diff(selectedFilters.type).length > 0 &&
         el.filters.size.diff(selectedFilters.size).length > 0
});
```

**Here is the working example..**

https://playcode.io/325371?tabs=console&script.js&output

***Note:*** you can change AND / OR condition as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this. For example, your solution is right but we need remove the curly brakets `{}` inside the every callback like this:

```js
filterWord => item.filters[key].includes(filterWord)
```

Another option could be converting the `selectedFilters` as an `filterValues` array, using the `flat()` method. This method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively. Now, we extract the `filters` of each `items` and convert it as `itemFilters` array using the `flat()` method again. Then we try to match them with the `filterValues` combining `every()` and `includes()` methods. Both will test whether all elements in the array include the elements of each `filter`.

The third option is very similar to your solution. In this case, we extracts the `selectedFilters` keys into a `types` array. Then for every `type` we call the `some()` method  combined with `includes()` method to test whether at least one element in the array is included in the `items.filters[type]`.

Here you have the implementation:

```js
const selectedFilters = {
    color: ['Red', 'Blue'],
    type: ['Shirt'],
    size: ['M']
};

const items = [
    {
        name: 'Item 1',
        filters: {
            color: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Black'],
            type: ['Shirt'],
            size: ['M']
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Item 2',
        filters: {
            color: ['Red'],
            type: ['Pants'],
            size: ['M']
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Item 3',
        filters: {
            color: ['Green', 'Blue', 'Red'],
            type: ['Shirt'],
            size: ['S']
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Item 4',
        filters: {
            color: ['Red', 'Blue'],
            type: ['Shirt'],
            size: ['M']
        }
    },
];

const filterItems = (items, selectedFilters) => {
    const filterKeys = Object.keys(selectedFilters);
    
    return items.filter(item => {
        return filterKeys.every(key => {
            // Ignore empty filters
            if (!selectedFilters[key].length) {
                return true;
            }
            return selectedFilters[key].every(filterWord => item.filters[key].includes(filterWord));
        });
    });
};

const results = filterItems(items, selectedFilters);

console.log('Your option: ');
results.forEach(function (item, key) {
 console.log('Name: ', item.name);
});

const filterValues = Object.values(selectedFilters).flat();
const results2 = items.filter(({filters}) => {
    const itemFilters = Object.values(filters).flat();
    return filterValues.every(filter => itemFilters.includes(filter));
})

console.log('Second option: ');
results2.forEach(function (item, key) {
 console.log('Name: ', item.name);
});


const types = Object.keys(selectedFilters);
const results3 = items.filter(
    item => types.every(
        type => selectedFilters[type].some(
            filter => item.filters[type].includes(filter)
        )
    )
);

console.log('Third option: ');
results3.forEach(function (item, key) {
 console.log('Name: ', item.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getFilteredResult = (data)=>{
    let res = true;
    for(d in data) {
            if(d == 'filters') {
                let obj = data[d];  
                for(key in obj) {
                    for(filterkey in selectedFilters) {         
                        if(filterkey == key) {
                            selectedFilters[filterkey].forEach(data=>{
                                 if(!obj[key].includes(data)){
                                    res=false;
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return res;
}
items.filter((data,index,arr)=> getFilteredResult(data))
```